# Can Endermen build Snowmen or Iron Golems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's currently two mobs that can be spawned by arranging blocks in a certain pattern: Snowmen and Iron Golems. If an Enderman produces this pattern, does it spawn a mob as if I had placed the blocks?

In other words: If I have a pumpkin farm next to an igloo, do I have to worry about my walls spontaneously turning into Snowmen?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yup, they sure can!

[image]

And [here's the reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/n7gn9/trying_to_make_endermen_build_snow_golems_aka_how/) where they talk about it.

Answer (score 19):

This YouTube video by [KapitanWalnut](http://www.youtube.com/user/KapitanWalnut) proves that Endermen can in fact create Snow Golems, and by extension Iron Golems:

Answer (score 12):

They can, as covered in the other answers.

However, Endermen cannot move snow or iron blocks; so they can only create a golem where the body pattern already exists. You could perhaps block such creation by ensuring there is always a block above any two-block-high section of snow, and so on.

Also, it is highly unlikely that an Enderman will pick up a pumpkin in the first place, and place it on your snow; you could make sure that there are no pumpkins near your base, and remove any you find moved closer by Endermen.

Comment: Pumpkins can migrate? (The obvious answer is "carried by Endermen", but is there some other game mechanic I'm not aware of?)

Comment: Sorry. I mean that over the long term, Endermen will repeatedly pick up and drop pumpkins, so a pumpkin may eventually reach your igloo through a random walk from a long distance.

Comment: I figured it was that, I just thought it would be cool if they could spread like mushrooms.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, according to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Trivia):

> Enderman are able to create snow golems and iron golems if they pick up a pumpkin and set it on already placed snow or iron blocks.

Haven't seen it happen myself, but seems plausible as they can move pumpkins.

Answer (score 1):

They can make Snow Golems no problem, however the only way they can make Iron Golems is to place a pumpkin on the iron part - they cannot pick up non-natural (player-created) blocks, and iron blocks are always player created.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows them making iron golems, which then attack the endermen:

Note that this isn't even with the iron blocks systematically arranged in T's.

Answer (score -1):

You know those carpet-like blocks that are snow? use them. They can't create golems from that type of snow. You will need silk-touch however.

Comment: try to elaborate, this question does not make much sense